# Trouble ramping up stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor

I am using a bipolar stepper motor with Fs = 238Hz, I want to ramp it up above its Fs, for this purpose I am stepping it up with an interval of 100ms but as soon as the motor reaches 240Hz it starts vibrating on its place and the motor stops, what am I doing wrong here? I am following TI's application note here.

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt482/slyt482.pdf

Comment: Are you sure Fs is in Hz, and not rpm? For your motor, how many steps/rev?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relatively high inductance of stepper motor windings means that as you increase the step speed for a given supply voltage, the current (and hence torque) produced falls off dramatically. Basically what you've done is step it at such a high frequency that the current in the winding cannot build to a point where enough torque is produced to overcome the magnetic detent force.

To fix this you need to increase the supply voltage to the motor when it is operating at the higher speeds.

Also note that the motor will become extremely inefficient at high speeds due to the large hysteresis/eddy current losses in the iron core from the high switching speeds. It is probably much better to either use a gearbox or some other type of motor if you want to run it above Fs.

Comment: just wanted to update you, i took your advice and used a 14V,4.2A DC supply and it worked, my motor ramped up to 252Hz, which is an achievement. Thanks